# cannot find “mysql” in PHPinfo();

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache

I have install php-mysql in my linux server,and restart apache server,but it cannot suport "mysql_connect" function.
I have search "mysql" in my phpinfo page,there is no "mysql" words in my phpinfo page.

How to solve this problem?

here is my phpinfo page,

http://www.xxpmt.com/myphpinfo.html (I have convert it to html page)

and here is my php.ini   from the path showed by phpinfo "/usr/local/services/php-5.4.6/lib"

http://www.xxpmt.com/phpini.txt

Comment: Please add more information for getting a help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `php.ini` file, check for `extension=mysql.so` under `Dynamic Extensions`. if there is any `;` before `extension=mysql.so`, remove that. If it is no `extension=mysql.so` please add it. Restart apache and check `phpinfo` again.

Note: It is recommended to use `mysqli` extension than `mysql`

Comment: I can not find extension=mysql.so  in my php.ini file

Comment: Then please add the line `extension=mysql.so` under `Dynamic Extensions` in php.

Comment: Can you go to the path `/usr/local/php/extensions` and check whether any extension files are there or not ? If  none of the `mysql` extensions are there, manually download, put it in this folder, update its name under `Dynamic Extensions`, then `RESTART` apache service (This is very important !!!)

Comment: it shows  
<code>apc.so  eaccelerator.so  memcache.so  openssl.so  ptlogin4.so  zip.so"</code>